# Protocol syntax inside block in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, protocols, objective-c-blocks

I have a method which accepts a block, the method signatures in objective C are

```
- (void) startWithFinishingBlock:(FinishingBlock _Nonnull)finishingBlock;
```

I have typedef FinishingBlock as below

```
typedef void (^FinishingBlock)(id<Operation> _Nonnull operation);
```

Now i am trying to call this methods from swift and having some trouble in writing it in swift. I am ending up with something like this.

```
    operation?.start(finishing: ({(operation : AnyObject) in

        } as? FinishingBlock)!)
```

But i know that it should not be `AnyObject`, i want here some object which conforms to `<Operation>` protocol. How i can define this in swift.

One additional thing that i have one Operation class and one `<Operation>` protocol in my code. So basically `Operation` class is conforming `<Operation>` protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you're unsure, you can just infer the correct types, e.g.:

```
operation?.start { operation in
    // ...
}
```

---

Just for the sake of completeness, the syntax (neither employing the above trailing closure syntax nor inferring the type) would be:

```
operation?.start(finishing: { (operation: MyApp.Operation) -> Void in
    // ...
})
```

Because your `Operation` protocol clashes with the Foundation `Operation` type (i.e. the new name for `NSOperation` in Swift 3), you have to qualify your protocol name with your target name (`MyApp` in my example above). This is the advantage of inferring the type of the parameter, as you don't have to deal with this.

Regardless, if you have the opportunity, I might recommend renaming your `Operation` protocol to avoid any confusion in the future.